# How can I get the position of an object during map function?

Tags: javascript

When you use for function you can save the position of an object like (example):

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var position = i;
}
```

but I don't know how I can get the position an how I can know if it is the last using map function

```
array.map((object) => {
})
```

Someone can help?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second parameter for the function provided to map is the current `index` of the element

```
arr.map((item, index) =>{
    if(index === arr.length-1) 
        console.log('last one')
})
```

Comment: and it's possible to know which is the last?

Answer (score 2):

In every of array methods (`map()`, `forEach()` etc..), the second parameter is an `index` of an array.

```js
const array1 = [1, 2, 3];
array1.map((value, i) => { console.log(i); });

const array2 = [1, 2, 3];
array2.forEach((value, i) => { console.log(i); });
```

Comment: Thank you Neel Rathod :)

Comment: @CatarinaBatista Happy to help

Answer (score 1):

```
array.map((object, index) => {
  var position = index;
})
```